# Query for dropdown in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have searched for it on Google, but can't find a query for dropdown in laravel.

Please give me solution for this, tutorials and code examples are welcome thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "query for dropdown"?

Answer (score 0):

There you go, you should populate it in this way

https://fuubar.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/poblar-drop-down-list-desde-la-db-con-laravel/

Comment: It's in spanish. If you post a link, make at least sure it is understandable.

Comment: He seems to be latin dude.....I tried to do my best...just good intentions here....He just needs to read the code in the article provided to understand it anyway, so the text doesn't matter at all

Comment: Why don't you extract the code from that article and improve your answer instead? If you understand it, use it.

Comment: I'm at work now, I was looking for something and I came across this question and I thought I could give him a quick reply. I admit you are right thought.....I should have give a complete answer or not answer at all

Answer (score 0):

```
{!! Form::select('userCountry',  \App\Libraries\Countries::countryList('alpha3', 'country_name') , 'USA' , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Here's enough of the Countries class for you to figure out how that works:

```
 /**
 * Builds a key/value pair
 * @param $key
 * @param $value
 * @return array|bool
 */
public static function countryList($key, $value)
{
    $json = self::countryData();
    $data = json_decode(self::countryData());

    if(!$data && !is_array($data)) {
        return false;
    }

    $out = [];

    foreach($data as $country) {
        if(property_exists($country, $key) && property_exists($country, $value)) {
            $out[$country->{$key}] = $country->{$value};
        }
    }

    return $out;
}

public static function countryData()
{
    return str_replace(' ', '', str_replace("\n", '', '
    [
        {
            "alpha2": "AF",
            "alpha3": "AFG",
            "country_code": "93",
            "country_name": "Afghanistan",
            "mobile_begin_with": [
                "7"
            ],
            "phone_number_lengths": [
                9
            ]
        },
        {
            "alpha2": "AL",
            "alpha3": "ALB",
            "country_code": "355",
            "country_name": "Albania",
            "mobile_begin_with": [
                "6"
            ],
            "phone_number_lengths": [
                8
            ]
        },
        {
            "alpha2": "DZ",
            "alpha3": "DZA",
            "country_code": "213",
            "country_name": "Algeria",
            "mobile_begin_with": [
                "5",
                "6",
                "7"
            ],
            "phone_number_lengths": [
                9
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's i am using CustomerModel as a model for customer details in that i am getting customer name for dropdown:

```
 $cust_details=CustomerModel::where('active_status',0)->get();
return view('FrontPage.itemadd')->with('cust_details',$cust_details);
```

in FrontPage.itemadd.blade i am using following code to put customer name in dropdown.

```
 <select id="cab_types" class="form-control" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" required>
 <option value="">Select</option>
    @foreach($cust_details as $cust)
    <option value="{{$cust->id}}">{{$cust->customer_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
          </select>
```